# Unexpected JSON token while reading DataTable EndArray While Deserializing Object

Tags: c#, json, exception, json-deserialization

While deserializing a JSON string to a specified type:

> Unexpected JSON token while reading DataTable EndArray

can any one help me on this please?

Comment: According to an online [JSON formatter and validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com), there is an unescaped backslash in a path `"Corporate Server\End User Personal Computing and Telecom Services Mart"` -- fwiw. When I fix that, the validator accepts it.

Comment: just check with this json string now

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: When i pasted the JSON string while asking the question it was parsable dont know why when i got posted it is different

Comment: OK, when I click "Edit" on your question, I see that the backslash is escaped in the text. So StackOverflow is translating backslash escapes, and that's not the problem you're having parsing it. Gotcha. Sorry, I was hoping it was just that.

Comment: I went ahead and took the liberty of changing it to "\\\\" so it'll show a double backslash in the question, to forestall confusion.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your de-serializing class `IncidentDetailContainer` there must be some data table property which is not getting serialized.

You need a class to represent the property which is of type Data Table.